# Positioning and opacity

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, positioning, transparency

I'm trying to include an image to my `beamer` using Tikz. The problem is that I don't find the code to position the image horizontally and vertically as well as being able to change its opacity.

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{frame}{Outline}
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(200,-200){\includegraphics[opacity=0,5][height=12cm]{Images/image.png}}
\end{picture}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. You haven't given us very much information to be able to help you. Can you edit your question to show a minimal compilable document that shows what you are trying to do?  Are you using `beamer`? Is the image supposed to be a background image for all your slides? On positioning, see e.g. [Beamer background image centered](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/26458)  On setting opacity for an included image see [Includegraphics: set image opacity](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/86500).

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to TeX-SE! Thanks for adding some code. Given that you load `tikz` and the `calc` library, I'd like to suggest

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node[opacity=0.5] at ($(current page.center)+(1,1)$)
{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-duck}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `overlay,remember picture` you can access and use absolute page coordinates, and with `calc` you can add coordinates, as illustrated.